# Python module can't see class file that was already loaded

Tags: python

I'm developing an interactive modeling platform called QREDIS.  It is composed of a set of interrelated modules, which get imported by a setup script and provide a set of model research functionality to the user.

As part of the setup, I load a class `QMod_Template` using

```
exec(open('QMod_Template.py').read())
```

This class is a base class for user-definable models; i.e. the user can define and save a new model `QMod_MyModel(QMod_Template)`.  All this works perfectly.  I don't want to force the user to later reload his model with `exec(open('QMod_MyModel.py').read())`, so I've created a function `LoadModel` in model `QREDIS_Model` which will load a specified model class file (basically a wrapper for the `exec` code).

When I execute this function, I get an error `NameError: name 'QMod_Template' is not defined`.  To summarize

First I load a class from a file:

```
exec(open('QMod_Template.py').read())
```

Then I import a module

```
import QREDIS_Model as QM
```

Then I try to load another model class file

```
QM.LoadModel('QMod_MyModel.py')
```

and get the NameError.

Essentially, `QREDIS_Model.LoadModel` needs to be able to access the already loaded `QMod_Template` class, but can't.  I have tried declaring QMod_Template as global in both the module and function, but no luck.

This should be a simple fix I think.  What am I missing?  I hope this extended question makes my issue much more clear.

Comment: What error/feedback did you get from the parser? Also why don't you use the normal `from x import xy` method?

Comment: Python doesn't have real globals; a "global" is only global to the module it's in. Import the modules you need from every other module that needs them.

Comment: The class file `QMod_Template` is loaded by a user into the ipython environtment - it is entirely separate (but to be used by) the `QM` module.  What it essentially comes down to is I have a variable in the "global" ipython space that I need a module to be able to access.